# React based Chrome extension - Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, webpack, google-chrome-extension

I built a `React` based `Chrome` extension, I want to do an `AJAX` call to my server from the extension.
So I'm using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` and `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener`.

I took the simplest example from [Chrome Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) , but I'm getting the following error:

`Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

I tried disabling all other `Chrome` extensions but that didn't help.
I'm quite confident it has to do with `webpack` and scoping but I couldn't figure it out.

[Sample code](https://gist.github.com/ohaddahan/b46165763ab5fd10173c1f39432736b7)

Comment: Any way I could reproduce this? Looks like either your server is not reachable or some error in your messaging

Comment: It's **really** required to show the actual code in almost any extension-related question. So far I can only guess you do sendResponse inside a nested asynchronous callback and hence need "return true" at the end of the listener, [more info](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage). Another common mistake is the wrong timing of sending/receiving but I need to see an [MCVE](/help/mcve) first.

Comment: @wOxxOm here is a code sample: https://gist.github.com/ohaddahan/b46165763ab5fd10173c1f39432736b7

Comment: @OhadDahan add it to the question.

Comment: If onMessage is inside a content script then you need to use a different sendMessage, [example](/a/14245504)